# React presentation vs container client side validation

Tags: reactjs

I am building a React app and trying to follow the pattern of separating presentational and container components as described [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

I'm confused as to where client-side validation would sit in this pattern?

For example, if I have the following components:

**Presentational**

- InputField (rendering an `<input>`)
- LoginForm (rendering a `<form>` with `<InputField>` for username and password)

**Container**

- LoginPage (renders the `<LoginForm>` and handles making API request)

My question is, where would client-side form validation fit into this? Would it go into `<LoginForm>` or should it go in the `<LoginForm>`?